# Stop image from disappearing after using transition with offset

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to do a transition and move an image -150 in y offset. It works but at the end of the movement the image disappears. How do i stop the image from disappearing? Any help appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ApplicationCore

struct StartUpScreen: View {
    
    private var moveLogoUp: AnyTransition {
        .offset(y:-150)
    }
    
    @State var moveUpLogo = false
    @State var fadeInText = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {

            Image("BackgroundFirstScreen")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                if !moveUpLogo {
                    Image("Logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(AppColors.backgroundColor, lineWidth: 8))
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .transition(moveLogoUp)
                     
                } else {
                    Text("Enter email")
                        .frame(width:100)
                        .opacity(fadeInText ? 1 : 0)
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                    self.moveUpLogo = true
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                    self.fadeInText = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct StartUpScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StartUpScreen()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have this structured you are animating the disappearance of the square. When you set move up logo to true, the square is transitioning out of the view hierarchy. Here's how you can do this - and without having to dispatch with delays!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct StartUpScreen: View {
    
    @State var logoYOffset = 0.0
    @State var textOpacity = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Image("BackgroundFirstScreen")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                Image("Logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(.green, lineWidth: 8))
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .offset(y: logoYOffset)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 3).delay(1.0),
                               value: logoYOffset)
                Text("Enter email")
                    .frame(width:100)
                    .opacity(textOpacity)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 3).delay(2.0),
                               value: textOpacity)
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .task {
            logoYOffset = -150.0
            textOpacity = 1.0
        }
    }
    
}

struct StartUpScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StartUpScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but i want to do it with .transition